Why can't I overlap data transfer and kernel execution in OpenCL?
I implemented an OpenCL code that takes an array of about 100 million elements and does a simple vector addition. Then I split the array in half and inserted it into two command queues.
However, in the code below, I found that the two command queues overlap each other and are not running. (Please refer to the attached image analyzed with CLtracer. The blue bar is the kernel, and the green bar is data transmission.) We also confirmed that if clFlush and clFinish are removed from the code, the speed decreases, but the operation does not work properly. .
I would like to overlap data transfer and kernel execution, while still having normal results. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work, so I'm asking for advice. For reference, I am using an Intel GPU, and the GPU supports multiple CPU queues and out of order queues.
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)
#define SIZE 134217728
#define NAME_LENGTH 256
#define ITERATION 5

size_t globalItemSize = SIZE;
size_t localItemSize = 64;

cl_platform_id *platformId = NULL;
cl_device_id deviceID = NULL;
cl_uint retNumPlatforms;
char platformName[NAME_LENGTH];
char deviceName[NAME_LENGTH];

FILE *kernelFile;
char *kernelSource;
size_t kernelSize;

cl_context context;
cl_command_queue commandQueue[2];
cl_program program;
cl_kernel kernel[2];

cl_mem aMemObj;
cl_mem bMemObj;
cl_mem cMemObj;

cl_mem aMemObj2;
cl_mem bMemObj2;
cl_mem cMemObj2;

cl_mem aPinnedObj;
cl_mem bPinnedObj;
cl_mem cPinnedObj;

cl_float *A;
cl_float *B;
cl_float *C;

cl_int err;
size_t bufferSz = sizeof(cl_float) * SIZE;

void SingleQueue() {
  err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&aMemObj);
  err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&bMemObj);
  err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&cMemObj);

  err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue[0], aMemObj, CL_TRUE, 0, bufferSz,
                             (void *)&A[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
  err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue[0], bMemObj, CL_TRUE, 0, bufferSz,
                             (void *)&B[0], 0, NULL, NULL);

  err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue[0], kernel[0], 1, NULL,
                               &globalItemSize, &localItemSize, 0, NULL, NULL);

  err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue[0], cMemObj, CL_TRUE, 0, bufferSz,
                            (void *)&C[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
}

void DoubleQueue() {
  size_t halfSz = bufferSz / 2;
  size_t halfOffset = SIZE / 2;
  cl_event write01;
  cl_event write11;
  cl_event write02;
  cl_event write12;
  cl_event kernel0;
  cl_event kernel1;

  err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&aMemObj);
  err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&bMemObj);
  err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[0], 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&cMemObj);

  err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[1], 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&aMemObj2);
  err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[1], 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&bMemObj2);
  err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[1], 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&cMemObj2);

  // Mid Phase 0
  err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue[0], aMemObj, CL_FALSE, 0, halfSz,
                             (void *)&A[0], 0, NULL, &write01);
  err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue[0], bMemObj, CL_FALSE, 0, halfSz,
                             (void *)&B[0], 1, &write01, &write02);
  clFlush(commandQueue[0]);
  clFlush(commandQueue[1]);
  // Start Phase 1 ***********************************
  err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue[0], kernel[0], 1, NULL,
                               &globalItemSize, &localItemSize, 1, &write02,
                               &kernel0);
  err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue[1], aMemObj2, CL_FALSE, halfSz,
                             halfSz, (void *)&A[halfOffset], 0, NULL, &write11);
  err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandQueue[1], bMemObj2, CL_FALSE, halfSz,
                             halfSz, (void *)&B[halfOffset], 0, NULL, &write12);
  clFlush(commandQueue[0]);
  clFlush(commandQueue[1]);
  // Start Phase 2 ***********************************
  err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue[1], kernel[1], 1, NULL,
                               &globalItemSize, &localItemSize, 1, &write12,
                               &kernel1);
  err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue[0], cMemObj, CL_FALSE, 0, halfSz,
                            (void *)&C[0], 1, &kernel0, NULL);
  clFlush(commandQueue[0]);
  clFlush(commandQueue[1]);
  // Start Phase 0 (Rolls over) ***********************************
  err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commandQueue[1], cMemObj2, CL_FALSE, halfSz, halfSz,
                            (void *)&C[halfOffset], 1, &kernel1, NULL);
  clFinish(commandQueue[0]);
  clFinish(commandQueue[1]);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &retNumPlatforms);
  platformId =
      (cl_platform_id *)malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) * retNumPlatforms);
  err = clGetPlatformIDs(retNumPlatforms, platformId, NULL);

  for (int32_t idxPlatform = 0; idxPlatform < retNumPlatforms; idxPlatform++) {
    err = clGetPlatformInfo(platformId[idxPlatform], CL_PLATFORM_NAME,
                            NAME_LENGTH, platformName, NULL);
    if (strstr(platformName, "Intel") != NULL) {
      err = clGetDeviceIDs(platformId[idxPlatform], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1,
                           &deviceID, NULL);
      err = clGetDeviceInfo(deviceID, CL_DEVICE_NAME, NAME_LENGTH, deviceName,
                            NULL);
      printf("Device Name = %s\n", deviceName);
    }
  }

  kernelFile = fopen("vecAddKernel.cl", "r");

  if (!kernelFile) {
    fprintf(stderr, "No file named vecAddKernel.cl was found\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  kernelSource = (char *)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
  kernelSize = fread(kernelSource, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, kernelFile);
  fclose(kernelFile);

  context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &deviceID, NULL, NULL, &err);
  program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&kernelSource,
                                      (const size_t *)&kernelSize, &err);
  err = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &deviceID, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  kernel[0] = clCreateKernel(program, "addVectors", &err);
  kernel[1] = clCreateKernel(program, "addVectors", &err);

  commandQueue[0] = clCreateCommandQueue(
      context, deviceID, CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE, &err);
  commandQueue[1] = clCreateCommandQueue(
      context, deviceID, CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE, &err);

  aMemObj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, bufferSz, NULL, &err);
  bMemObj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, bufferSz, NULL, &err);
  cMemObj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, bufferSz, NULL, &err);

  aMemObj2 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, bufferSz, NULL, &err);
  bMemObj2 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, bufferSz, NULL, &err);
  cMemObj2 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, bufferSz, NULL, &err);

  aPinnedObj = clCreateBuffer(
      context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, bufferSz, NULL, &err);
  bPinnedObj = clCreateBuffer(
      context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, bufferSz, NULL, &err);
  cPinnedObj = clCreateBuffer(
      context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, bufferSz, NULL, &err);

  A = (cl_float *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(commandQueue[0], aPinnedObj, CL_TRUE,
                                     CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, bufferSz, 0, NULL, NULL,
                                     &err);
  B = (cl_float *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(commandQueue[0], bPinnedObj, CL_TRUE,
                                     CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, bufferSz, 0, NULL, NULL,
                                     &err);
  C = (cl_float *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(commandQueue[0], cPinnedObj, CL_TRUE,
                                     CL_MAP_READ, 0, bufferSz, 0, NULL, NULL,
                                     &err);

  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    A[i] = i + 1;
    B[i] = (i + 1) * 2;
  }

  clock_t begin_double = clock();
  for (uint32_t idx = 0; idx < ITERATION; idx++) {
    DoubleQueue();
  }
  clock_t end_double = clock();

  double time_spent_double = (double)(end_double - begin_double) * 0.001;
  printf("Double Queue Evaluation------------\n");
  printf("Double Queue = %f ms\n", time_spent_double / ITERATION);

  for (uint32_t idx = 0; idx < 2; idx++) {
    err = clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue[idx]);
    err = clReleaseKernel(kernel[idx]);
  }
  err = clReleaseProgram(program);
  err = clReleaseMemObject(aMemObj);
  err = clReleaseMemObject(bMemObj);
  err = clReleaseMemObject(cMemObj);
  err = clReleaseMemObject(aPinnedObj);
  err = clReleaseMemObject(bPinnedObj);
  err = clReleaseMemObject(cPinnedObj);
  err = clReleaseContext(context);
  return 0;
}

CLtracer result
enter image description here
